# Order of Asynchronous Firebase Requests for UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, asynchronous

I'm trying to maintain the order of elements in a Swift array after performing a series of asynchronous network requests. Specifically, I have an array of IDs, eventIds, which I pass to a Firebase function to download the corresponding EventObjects.

The EventObjects need to be sorted in the same order as the original eventIds array. The issue I'm encountering is that the asynchronous nature of the network requests means that they don't necessarily complete in the order they were started.

To address this, I use a DispatchGroup to notify when all requests are complete and then sort the results. However, the issue I'm facing is that my UITableView sometimes displays the events in the wrong order for a split second before they are rearranged into the correct order.

```
 func downloadRequestEventsFromFirebase(withIds: [String], completion: @escaping (_ events: [EventObject]) -> Void) {
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "MM dd, yyyy"

    var foundEvents = [String: EventObject]() // temp dictionary to store all of the results
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    for eventId in withIds {
        group.enter()
        FirebaseReference(.Event).document(eventId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            defer {
                group.leave()
            }

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

            if snapshot.exists {
                let event = EventObject(_dictionary: snapshot.data()!)
                let eventDate = dateFormatter.date(from: event.eventDate)

                if eventDate != nil && (currentDateTime <= eventDate!  ||  currentDateTime.longDate() == eventDate?.longDate()) {
                    // Save the result for later sorting
                    foundEvents[eventId] = event
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This block gets called once all results have been received
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        // Put the results into the desired order
        var eventsArray = [EventObject]()
        for eventId in withIds {
            if let event = foundEvents[eventId] {
                eventsArray.append(event)
            }
        }

        // Make one call to the completion handler
        completion(eventsArray)
    }
}
```

Before calling the downloadRequestEventsFromFirebase(withIds:completion:) function, I'm performing another asynchronous network request using Firebase to download a list of RequestObjects, each containing an eventId among other data.

```
  private func loadUserRequests() {
    print("loading event requests")
    if let currentUser = FUser.currentUser() {
        FirebaseListener.shared.downloadArtistRequestsFromFirebase(withId: currentUser.objectId) { (artistRequests) in
            let eventIds = artistRequests.map { $0.eventId }
            FirebaseListener.shared.downloadRequestEventsFromFirebase(withIds: eventIds) { (eventObjects) in

                var temporaryRequestEventPairs: [(RequestObject, EventObject)] = []

                for request in artistRequests {
                    if let event = eventObjects.first(where: { $0.eventId == request.eventId }) {
                        temporaryRequestEventPairs.append((request, event))
                    }
                }


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.requestEventPairs = temporaryRequestEventPairs
                    print("count: \(self.requestEventPairs.count)")
                    self.requestsTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 func downloadArtistRequestsFromFirebase(withId: String, completion: @escaping (_ events: [RequestObject]) -> Void) {
    
    var foundRequests: [RequestObject] = []
    FirebaseReference(.Request)
        .whereField(kREQUESTER, isEqualTo: isLookingFor())
        .whereField(kREQUESTARTISTID, isEqualTo: FUser.currentId())
        .order(by: kREQUESTDATE, descending: true)
        .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                completion(foundRequests)
                return
            }
            
            if !snapshot.isEmpty {
                for request in snapshot.documents {
                    let requestObject = request.data()
                    foundRequests.append(RequestObject(_dictionary: requestObject))
                }
                
    
                completion(foundRequests)
            }
            else {
                completion(foundRequests)
            }
        }
}
```

From the RequestObjects, I extract the eventIds and pass them as an array to downloadRequestEventsFromFirebase(withIds:completion:). The order of these eventIds is crucial as I want to maintain the same order in the downloaded EventObjects.

The problem I'm facing is that, despite using a DispatchGroup to manage the order of the results, my UITableView sometimes displays the events in the wrong order for a split second before correcting itself.

I'm looking for a way to ensure that the order of EventObjects matches the order of eventIds passed in, and to prevent the temporary incorrect ordering of the data in the UITableView.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii1b5.jpg) img 1 is when self.requestsTableView.reloadData() is first hit and it displays the incorrect order
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqSwz.jpg) img 2 is a ssplit second after (correct order)

[image: When self.requestsTableView.reloadData() is first hit]

[image: A split second after image (1)]